# Filter from source attribute in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I Need to filter out all images with `src` domain like `abs.twimg.com`

```
<img class="ProfileCard-avatarImage js-action-profile-avatar" src="https://abs.twimg.com/..." alt="">
```

What's the easiest way to achieve this in Javascript?

Comment: `$('img').filter(function(){ this.src.indexOf('abs.twimg.com')>-1; })`

Comment: @Rayon The perfect solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var selectedImages = document.querySelectorAll( "img[src*='abs.twimg.com']" );
```

check this [doc](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview)

> `E[foo*="bar"]`   - an E element whose foo attribute value contains the
>   substring bar

If you want to select images **other than** those containing `abs.twimg.com`, then try using a `not selector`

```
var selectedImages = document.querySelectorAll( "img:not([src*='abs.twimg.com'])" );
```

Answer (score 0):

if by "filter out" you mean *remove*, then you can do the following:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("img"); 
// or document.querySelectorAll if you don't care too much for compability
for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
    if(nodes[i].src.indexOf("abs.twimg.com") !== -1){
        nodes[i].parentElement.removeChild(nodes[i]); // remove
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, for "fiter out" I meant skip those `img` with that domain in `src`